# SOAP returns DateTime with timezone offset added to minutes

Tags: date-time, soap, timezone

I am using the Ruby gem 'viewpoint/spws' (from a RHEL 6 server) to insert items into a Sharepoint list via SOAP.

It seems that the DateTime fields being passed are being incorrectly interpreted by the server. Examining the SOAP messages being passed, I see that the response is indicating that the timezone offset (-05:00 for EST in my case) is being negated then added to the minutes portion of the time.

Example:

SOAP Request: `2012-12-26T14:00:00-05:00`
SOAP Response: `"2012-12-26 14:05:00"`

Example:

SOAP Request: 2012-12-26T13:30:00-05:00
SOAP Response: "2012-12-26 13:35:00"

Examining the list in Sharepoint also shows this "+5 minute" entry.

Also, if I submit the request without the offset, this is entered as expected.

Example:

SOAP Request: `2012-12-26T13:30:00Z`
SOAP Response: `"2012-12-26 13:30:00"`

I've been looking for an explanation of this behavior but I'm not having any luck finding one. Any suggestions would be appreciated.